# Partitioning a large data set with 150+ columns into 5 parts

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large with 150+ columns and 1 target column with over 5000 rows.
I would like to split this into 5 smaller sets and include the target column in each one to  create some heatmaps.

Any advice on this?

I have tried this so far, but it doesn't work

```
train_indices <- sample(5,ncolumn(data),replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2))
train1 <- data[train_indices==1,]
train2 <- data[train_indices==2,]
train3 <- data[train_indices==3,]
train4 <- data[train_indices==4,]
train5 <- data[train_indices==5,]
summary(train1)
summary(train2)
summary(train3)
summary(train4)
summary(train5)
```

Comment: Replace `ncolum` by `ncol`

Comment: Do you want that some columns are present in more than one `trainX`?

Comment: hi Julien, thank you for this. this is really helpful. i need 1 column- the target column present in all of the  subsets

Comment: train_indices <- sample(5,ncol(data[colnames(data) != y]), replace = T)             this runs for me.                                   
train1 <- cbind(data[y], data[colnames(data) != y][train_indices==1])    when i run this though, i have a message saying undefined columns selected.      do i need to individually identify each column i want in each subset?

Comment: Please comment under my answer below

Comment: What is in `y`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `mtcars` as an example, here is a possible solution

```r
data <- mtcars
y    <- "cyl" # Assume that "cyl" is the target variable

train_indices <- sample(5,ncol(data[colnames(data) != y]), replace = T)
train1 <- cbind(data[y], data[colnames(data) != y][train_indices==1])
train1

                    cyl  mpg drat vs am
Mazda RX4             6 21.0 3.90  0  1
Mazda RX4 Wag         6 21.0 3.90  0  1
Datsun 710            4 22.8 3.85  1  1
Hornet 4 Drive        6 21.4 3.08  1  0
Hornet Sportabout     8 18.7 3.15  0  0
Valiant               6 18.1 2.76  1  0
Duster 360            8 14.3 3.21  0  0
Merc 240D             4 24.4 3.69  1  0
Merc 230              4 22.8 3.92  1  0
Merc 280              6 19.2 3.92  1  0
Merc 280C             6 17.8 3.92  1  0
Merc 450SE            8 16.4 3.07  0  0
Merc 450SL            8 17.3 3.07  0  0
Merc 450SLC           8 15.2 3.07  0  0
Cadillac Fleetwood    8 10.4 2.93  0  0
Lincoln Continental   8 10.4 3.00  0  0
Chrysler Imperial     8 14.7 3.23  0  0
Fiat 128              4 32.4 4.08  1  1
Honda Civic           4 30.4 4.93  1  1
Toyota Corolla        4 33.9 4.22  1  1
Toyota Corona         4 21.5 3.70  1  0
Dodge Challenger      8 15.5 2.76  0  0
AMC Javelin           8 15.2 3.15  0  0
Camaro Z28            8 13.3 3.73  0  0
Pontiac Firebird      8 19.2 3.08  0  0
Fiat X1-9             4 27.3 4.08  1  1
Porsche 914-2         4 26.0 4.43  0  1
Lotus Europa          4 30.4 3.77  1  1
Ford Pantera L        8 15.8 4.22  0  1
Ferrari Dino          6 19.7 3.62  0  1
Maserati Bora         8 15.0 3.54  0  1
Volvo 142E            4 21.4 4.11  1  1
```

Comment: Y is the first column of my data  it is a numeric  binary column

Comment: So replace `y <- "cyl"` by `y <- "Y"`